# Javascript DOM | Find element by inner Text and replace every element that matches

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I scraped from the internet and done something to it, I don't know anything about Javascript so don't blame me if this code is a total mess :)

My Code:

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var searchText = "VRX";
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
    found = aTags[i];
    break;
  }
}

Array.from(found).forEach(
    function(element, index, array) {
       document.getElementsByClassName("nova").style = "text-shadow:0.5px 0.5px 5px gold;color:gold;background: url(https://static.nulled.to/public/assets/sparkling.gif);-webkit-animation: randclanim 2s infinite linear;";
    }
);
```

HTML:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do! Dude please ask question clearly.

Comment: I apologize that I don’t have the knowledge to ask clearly.   Let me explain again. The first part of the code gets the first element/tag that contains the word “VRX”, I want that it gets every element that contains “VRX” in this nova class and adds the style value for each nova class that contains the word “VRX.

Comment: Yeah that's gr8 but nothing you've just commented is posted in your actual question...

Comment: Well, now u know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see screenShot of your code, you should parsing span elements for example I write below code:

```js
// if you want just A elements use below line 
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("span");


 
  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
   console.log(els[i].textContent +"--" + i );
     els[i].className.lastIndexOf('nova')!=-1 && els[i].textContent.lastIndexOf('VRX')!=-1  ?  els[i].style = "text-shadow:0.5px 0.5px 5px gold;color:gold;background: url(https://static.nulled.to/public/assets/sparkling.gif);-webkit-animation: randclanim 2s infinite linear;" : 0;
   
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div>
  <span class="nova">HI</span>
   <br>
   <br>
  <a > VRX </a>
</div>
<div>
<a> <span class="nova">VRX</span></a>
</div>
 
</body>
```

I hope it useful ;)

Comment: Sorry for interrupting u again, this code works perfectly fine. Example im writing a message in the shoutbox, is it possible to optimize the code that it refreshes itself or reruns to add the style value? I already tried it with looping the code, but this makes the website very laggy.

Comment: @VRX ,Dude upload part of your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and link to me